# MVC model List of Strings

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am new to MVC. I have a model where I want to keep a list of Items that user selected while checking the checkboxes in the view. How can I achieve this. Kindly help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you show the code you have tried so far? What's stopping you to achieve this? I could help fixing the code if it doesn't work.

Comment: Post some code and be more specific, that's too broad

Comment: Guys the thing is I dont know how would I access the List inside my view. My model contains this list and I just want to add the name of Item checked

Comment: You mean: in a view, you want to access a list that's in a model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're looking for but try this:

```
@foreach (var listItem in Model.listName)
{
    <p>@listItem</p>
}
```

Comment: Thanks I guess now i can use javascript to Check which items have been checked and add them to my model's list